# Nuxt / Vue : Component call a Method in a page

Tags: vue.js, methods, components, nuxt.js

There is my issue:

My page listing.vue list all products.
Theses products are in a Component, `Product.vue`.

In this component, there is a button to add this product to a selection, displaying on the listing.vue.

page/listing.vue :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <product v-for="...." />
     
    <section>
      <ul>
        <li>Produit 1</li>
        <li>Produit 3</li>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    addToSelection(id) {
      // Code to add Product to <ul> //
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

component/product.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ product.title }}
    <button @click="addToSelection(product.id)">
      Add product to selection
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['product'],
}
</script>
```

The problem is nuxt render an error:

> the addToSelection method is unknown.

Comment: You should use `<Product />` or `<product></product>` but not a mix as explained here: https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should emit from your children to your parent

`Product.vue`

```html
<button @click="emitProductToParent(product.id)">

...
methods: {
  emitProductToParent(id) {
    this.$emit('input', id)
  }
}
```

`Listing.vue`

```html
<Product @input="addToSelection" v-for="...." />
```

You cannot use a method that is not in the component your event listener is on. And even if you could, this is not the way to do. Use:

- props to pass things down to children
- emit to pass things up to parents

As explained in the official documentation here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events